# using smart_open on a large database connect to write to s3 with python

Tags: python, boto3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to dump a very large table from a database connection to s3 using smart_open

```
 cur = con.cursor().execute(sql_query)
ret = cur.fetchmany(3)
with open(s3_path, 'wb', transport_params=transport_params) as fout:
    while len(ret) > 0:
        lines=ret = cur.fetchmany(10000)
        for line in lines:
           fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work just make sure you convert line to 
`str(line)`
deal with ( ) and add a new line character
also, you must 
`fout.write(bytes(row,'utf-8'))`